# Conditional role-giving in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm new to Python. I'm coding a mini-game for a Discord server. I want to make a command that changes the role of members depending on their role, and sends the message "You cannot kill {mention}, he is immortal.", if the argument mentions a player who does not have one of the roles: "3 lives", "2 life", 1 life", or "dead". I tried using a list and a "not in" operator:

```
elif role.name not in ['3 lives', '2 lives', '1 life', 'Dead']:
        await ctx.send("You can't kill {}, he/she is immortal".format(victim.mention))
        break
```

But the function was called even when the victim didn't have those roles.
Here is my code:

```
# $kill command
@client.command(name = 'kill')
@commands.has_any_role('3 lives', '2 lives', '1 life')
@commands.cooldown(1, 57600, commands.BucketType.user)
async def kill(ctx, victim: discord.Member):
    for role in victim.roles:
        #if you try to kill yourself 
        if victim == ctx.message.author: 
            await ctx.reply("You can't kill yourself.")
            kill.reset_cooldown(ctx)
            break

        #if you try to kill dead
        elif role.name == 'Dead': 
            await ctx.reply("You can't kill {}, this user is already dead.".format(victim.mention))
            kill.reset_cooldown(ctx)
            break
        
        else:
            #makes people have 2 lives
            if role.name == '3 lives': 
                newrole = discord.utils.get(victim.guild.roles, name='2 lives')
                await victim.add_roles(newrole)                    
                await victim.remove_roles(role)
                await ctx.reply("You attacked {}, now this user has 2 lives.".format(victim.mention))
                break

            #makes people have 1 life
            elif role.name == '2 lives': 
                newrole = discord.utils.get(victim.guild.roles, name='1 life')
                await victim.add_roles(newrole)
                await victim.remove_roles(role)
                await ctx.reply("You attacked {}, now this user has 1 life".format(victim.mention))
                break

            #makes people dead
            elif role.name == '1 life': 
                newrole = discord.utils.get(victim.guild.roles, name='Dead')
                await victim.add_roles(newrole)
                await victim.remove_roles(role)
                await ctx.reply("You attacked {}, now this user is dead.".format(victim.mention))
                break
```

**Update 1:** The condition that should notify about the impossibility of killing a member who does not have the roles "3 life", "2 life", "1 life" or "Dead" was always true, since it checked for the presence of other roles that do not belong to the list of available for killing , including @everyone.

Comment: You don't check if the message author has the roles, so the function will be called nonetheless. If you are killing someone who are already dead, you are checking for any other role besides yours, and since someone doesn't have it, it is false and elaborates through your if block.

Comment: @OzgurO. I actually check by using `@commands.has_any_role('3 lives', '2 lives', '1 life')`

Comment: What happens after the function is called? What is the problem? If you call the kill function via chat, the above code block will execute. You might be having issues while using the `break` keyword, it'll exit out the for loop too, so if you have any other previous roles that are NOT in your list, the rest will not execute.

Comment: @OzgurO. A member that mentioned in the message simply loses his current role and receives new. I am using the `break` keyword to fix the multiple superfluous replies that I was experiencing. Maybe `break` is not needed in some places and I should remake the code. The problem is that a player who tries to kill a member who does not have roles from a certain list receives a cooldown for 16 hours. The rest of the exceptions are worked out, and the cooldown is canceled if the player makes a mistake. The rest of the code works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, it definitely works.

```
check1 = discord.utils.get(victim.roles, name = '3 lives')
check2 = discord.utils.get(victim.roles, name = '2 lives')
check3 = discord.utils.get(victim.roles, name = '1 lives')
check4 = discord.utils.get(victim.roles, name = 'Dead')
check_all = [check1, check2, check3, check4]

#if you try to kill immortal
elif not any(check_all):
    await ctx.reply("You can't kill {}, this user is immortal.".format(victim.mention))
    attack.reset_cooldown(ctx)
    break
```